# Absolutely fried on implementing rotation in a C++ binary search tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I've spent *several* hours trying to make this darn thing work, and at this point my brain is so fried I can barely explain what I'm trying to do. I'll admit it's homework, but I'm 100% lost on how to make progress, and it's one of the very few things I have left in this project. The rotation functions are taken (with permission) from lecture notes, but by god I can't get them to work.

contains() is supposed to check whether an element exists somewhere in the tree, and if that element has been searched for `search_threshold` times, rotate it one position higher in the tree.

I tried my own messy solution for a while, but it didn't work nearly the way it needed to. For now I was just shooting to get a really basic case for rotation working, where the node that's being moved up has no children, but even that seems to be dropping nodes. Any tips how to get back on track?

```
//BSTNode is a struct with
T element, 
BSTNode *left = NULL, 
BSTNode *right = NULL, 
BSTNode *parent = NULL, 
int search_count = 0
```

Abbreviated code as follows:

```
template <typename T>
void BST< T >::rotateWithLeftChild(BSTNode *& k2)
{
    BSTNode *k1 = k2->left;
    k2->left = k1->right;
    k1->right = k2;
    k2 = k1;
}

template <typename T>
void BST< T >::rotateWithRightChild( BSTNode *& k2)
{
    BSTNode *k1 = k2->right;
    k2->right = k1->left;
    k1->left = k2;
    k2 = k1;
}

template <typename T>
void BST< T >::doubleWithRightChild( BSTNode *& k3 )
{
    rotateWithLeftChild( k3->right );
    rotateWithRightChild( k3 );
}

template <typename T>
void BST< T >::doubleWithLeftChild( BSTNode *& k3 )
{
    rotateWithRightChild( k3->left );
    rotateWithLeftChild( k3 );
}

template <typename T>
bool BST< T >::contains(const T& v, BSTNode *&t)
{
    // If the node doesn't exist, return false
    if (t == NULL)
        return false;
    // If the node exists, return true
    if (t->element == v)
    {
        // Increment search count
        t->search_count++;
        // If search count is above threshold,
        if (t->search_count >= threshold)
        {
            cout << "Search count above threshold" << endl;
            // Reset search count
            t->search_count = 0;

            if (t == root)
                return true;

            // Faaaaaairly confident that my bug is here
            if (t->left != NULL && t->right != NULL)
            {
                cout << "parent element: " << t->parent->element << endl;
                if (t == t->parent->left)
                    rotateWithLeftChild(t->parent);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // Otherwise, return the OR of the children's contains()
    else
        return (contains(v, t->left) || contains(v,t->right));
}
```

Comment: [std::rotate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Do I need to do anything to implement that on a Tree of my own design? Looks like it uses iterators, which I don't have set up.

Comment: I don't have time to do a full answer, but suggest you do a Google image search for a picture showing the tree rotations and implement based on the image. Then build several small test cases to check that it's doing what you think it is.

Comment: @Richard Yeah, I've been trying something to that effect, looking over lecture slides, but something about it is really throwing me off. I imagine I'm coming off as just fishing for the answer, but it's been hours and figured a new perspective was worth a shot. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give a failure case? By that I mean code that sets up a *simple* tree, then attempts a rotation that fails somehow?

Comment: @Beta Can't figure out a good way to demonstrate here, but the node being rotated up seems to become its own parent? And its left child disappears completely. Tree only has 7 elements.

Comment: So the error doesn't occur when there are only 6 elements? Can you edit your question to give us a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @sagev9000 Learn to use your debugger.  Then instead of staring at code and looking at lecture slides, you get to run your program step-by-step and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Start by making your job easier.

Left and right should be unique ptrs.  Parent a naked ptr.

Get left / right returns a naked ptr.  Snip left/right returns a unique ptr, *and* nulls parent in the unique ptr'd tree.

Set takes a unique ptr.

Rotate functions *take* a unique ptr, and *return* a unique ptr.

People who call rotate functions must snip from parent, rotate that tree, then set it back into parent.

```
BSTNode *k1 = k2->left;
k2->left = k1->right;
k1->right = k2;
k2 = k1;
```

this is classic read-only code.  We have pointers and references flying around.  It is as short as it can be, but that is because it was solved then hand-optimized.  It doesn't educate except possibly as a puzzle.

We want to go from:

```
      a
  b      R
L  c
```

to:

```
      b
  L      a
        c  R
```

So in pseudocode:

```
up<Node> rot_left( up<Node> a ){
  auto b=a->snip_left();
  auto c=b->snip_right();
  a->set_left(std::move(c));
  b->set_right(std::move(a));
  return b;
}
```

I think that is right.  To check write a tree validator and dumper.  Assert we never overwite a non-emoty branch.  Assert that trees are valid after and before each operation.  Dump the tree before after making it look like tha a b c R L tree.  Dump the tree after.  Confirm it looks right.  Compare what I descrived to your lecture notes and the internet.

Theae steps can be done without rewriting your code to use unique ptrs; just having snip/set/get methods that maintain invarients is enough.

From this rewriting, I suspect the problem is your rotate code doesn't maintain parent ptrs correctly.  The snip/set/get triad will do this for you if you use it carefully; the unique ptr but is to distinguish between owning (snip/set) operations from observing (get) operations.